# Meaning of options in Energy plug

Tags: release-loki, system

The *Energy* plug shows the following options for *When the lid is closed*

[image]

I get what *Suspender* (suspend), and *Apagar* (shut-down) mean. But, what do *Halt*, and *Block* mean?

BTW: the Spanish plug needs translation.

Answer (score 1):

In the English (US) version the third item is Lock (and not Block) and it locks the screen.

[image]

Comment: And what does `Halt` do?

Comment: I am not sure but I think that there is a difference between "Halt" and "Shutdown" because the latter performs a power off as well (but not the former). Actually I did not have any source to confirm this or some time to test it.